# perl oneliner : to match a pattern and substitute part of the matched pattern

Tags: perl, sed

how to match a pattern which is as follows

```
input:  0xabcdxx 0xdefxxcf 0x12345xad
output: 0xabcd00 0xdef00cf 0x123450ad
```

I want the x to be replaced by 0 but the initial 0x at the start of a word should remain the same. Can a perl/sed oneliner is possible to get this way?
Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
echo "0xabcdxx 0xdefxxcf 0x12345xad" | sed 's/\b0x/Y/g; s/x/0/g; s/Y/0x/g'
```

First substitute the `0x` patterns at the word beginnings with a distinguishable pattern (I used `'Y'`). Then replace all `x` with `0` and replace `Y` back with `0x`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '0xabcdxx 0xdefxxcf 0x12345xad' |
   perl -pe's/(?<!^0)(?<!\s0)x/0/g'
0xabcd00 0xdef00cf 0x123450ad
```

Maybe a teeny bit faster:

```
$ echo '0xabcdxx 0xdefxxcf 0x12345xad' |
   perl -pe's/x(?<!^0x)(?<!\s0x)/0/g'
0xabcd00 0xdef00cf 0x123450ad
```

Comment: An explanation of how this works would be useful. Also both of those still replace the first `x` in `0xabc`. Do you need the `\S` here?

Comment: but the initial 0x is being changed to 00 if i am trying that way. the initial 0x should remain as 0x for all the words in the line.